# Steam launch commands: a way to launch a little script?

Tags: steam

I know you can personalize the launch of a game by adding specific commands on Steam. Can you add a command that runs a little .bat script?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Powerlord The little script (i said .bat because there exists a dos version of Steam so I though it was more likely to work, but I can write the script in any language) should update some files, edit them, and copy some test to the clipboard right before the game launches.

Comment: You could do a custom Steam.exe that basically launches your script and after that launches Steam. Should be pretty easy to accomplish

Comment: @JonasDralle That isn't really what I want, since I want the script to be ran just right before the specific _game_ starts, not Steam. I might want to run Steam and play another game for which I don't need the script to be launched. That's why I want the script to be linked to the game, not to Steam.

Comment: You coould scan the active processes of your PC. The program keeps an eye on your machina and as soon as your game.exe is active it automatically activates the script.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look into the Task Planner of Windows. As soon as game.exe launches you can run the script. I dont know if windows supports running an specific .exe as a teigger, but you should at least check it out because it's really easy to set up and you wont require 3th-Party gimmickery

Answer (score 9):

**No, but you can achieve the same result with a bit of a hack.**

Launch arguments aren't related to batch files. You can use a batch file to launch something with launch arguments but not the other way around. However, if you want to launch the game through Steam and make the batch file run before the game, you can use the steps below to achieve that.

1. Go to the game's installation folder and find the `.exe` file for the game. Rename it from something like `game.exe` to `game_real.exe`, for example.
2. At the end of your batch file, add a command that runs your executable, obviously replacing `game_real.exe` with your renamed game's executable:

   `start "" game_real.exe`
3. Find a tool that compiles a `.bat` batch file into a `.exe` executable. I haven't tested it but you could try [this one](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) at your own risk. Use this to compile your batch file. You may want to play around with the settings to make it not visible and whatever else you want.
4. Rename the resulting executable to the original name of the game's executable, `game.exe` in this example. Put this in the same folder as your game's executable.

That should be it. The batch file will run in place of the game when launched from Steam, then it will launch the actual game when it completes your desired actions. If the game has an update that changes the game's executable, your script will be replaced with that. Verifying the integrity of the game cache files will also replace your script with the real executable again. If that happens, just repeat these steps, discarding the old renamed game executable.

Comment: I also wanted to propose this method :)

Comment: This is a way to make a shortcut to a game.. This is not a way to make the steam launcher commands parse something you just want to add to it.. as is what was asked for.

Comment: I used this to automatically delete a file that BioShock creates that essentially says, "I'm running and I'll be deleted when I shut down properly but not if I crash". Since the game crashes a ton and the existence of that file at game startup resets all settings (even including key bindings), I made the batch script delete the file before the game started.

Comment: @James This is not a way to make a shortcut to a game. This is a way to run a batch file before the game starts, as the question asked. It is not possible to make launch arguments on their own run a batch file because those are entirely different things. I am giving the only possible answer that fits his intent. Unless you want me to just say "it's not possible" without suggesting an actual alternative which seems like a very dissatisfactory answer to me. But your downvote on my answer and your upvote on the answer that does exactly that implies you think actual solutions are a bad thing.

Comment: While this does work, it's not relevant to steam's launch options, which is what this question is about. He may as well just have a bat file that executes commands and launches the game exe and start it through a shortcut. It would be the same effect, but less work required.

Comment: @Keavon Hmmmm. I guess I am torn at the title and first sentence vs the rest of the question. I took it as is there a way to get the steam urls to do more, like run a bat file.. which no they can't do. But if you replace what it is targeting at, like you are suggesting, then the results are what is expected.

Comment: Even if this doesn't exactly answer the question it's still a better solution than telling it's not possible since this answer still fullfills the requirements of the question.

Comment: @Chippies Sure, but that wouldn't allow you to start the game through Steam since you'd have to use the shortcut.

Comment: @James Please see my edit to the opening sentence. Since my answer now says it's not possible and then also suggests a way to achieve the same effect, I would kindly request that you reconsider your vote which I feel is unjustified in its current negative state.

Comment: Launching the script directly from Steam sounded like the best solution for me, but since it's not possible, Keavon's solution should work as wel.
But: what if future updates need to change/update the game launcher itself? Wouldn't that cause some problems? Also, what if the game detects that the executable launcher has been modified and considers that a malicious hack? I mean, I might violate some EULA rules and get banned?

Comment: @user3501165 If there is an update that changes the game's executable, the executable you created from the batch file will be replaced with the updated one. In that case, you will have to delete the old, renamed game executable, rename the new one, and put the exe batch file back. This will also be necessary if you verify the integrity of the game cache files. It will not be considered a malicious hack, it is absolutely not against any EULA, and it will certainly not get you banned.

Comment: @Keavon you can't say for sure that it will not be considered a malicious hack, especially in MMOs with their own anti-hacking software. I have played some MMOs (not on steam at the time) that had such finicky anti-hack implementations, it would kick you out of the game for the most random reasons.

Comment: @Chippies I meant it would not violate anything with Steam or get you banned from there. However, I doubt this would affect even the most finicky anti-cheat programs since it's simply launching the game and Steam injects its overlay and API into everything launched by its running apps.

Comment: The problem is not that it's invasive or anything, but that the game isn't running from exe with the original name. There are some (not many) games that don't like that. To be fair, many MMOs don't like AutoHotkey either.

Answer (score 8):

For those Google pilgrims arriving in the future:

'Add a game...' → 'Add a Non-Steam Game' → 'Browse...' → 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe'.

On new shortcut "cmd.exe" → 'Properties':

- Name: `Awesome Game`
- Target: `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k C:\Location\Of\File.bat`
- Start In: the path your game lives in, like `"C:\Steam\steamapps\common\AwesomeGame"`

Obviously, the .bat file should contain something like `"start C:\Steam\steamapps\common\AwesomeGame\a_game.exe"`

Comment: thx, it works like a charm

Comment: thank you kind sir! Lowly Pilgrim passing through, and that looks like it might be the simplest solution aside from what BlueWizard suggested above. I'm kind of surprised/embarrassed that I didn't think of it myself. Only thing is wouldn't that break most of Steam's integration/overlay features? Or would it pick up on the fact the batch launched the target game's executable? For instance, would steam realize I'm actually playing awesomegame and display that on my friends list? Just a thought.

Comment: thinking about it a bit more, if launching the executable directly doesn't trigger whatever steam integration the game has, one could also just do "steam://rungameid/[appid goes here]". Then the only problem is if the game has a multiple choice when launching (As I recall, it will use the default profile instead of asking you to choose. For most games, that's a nonissue.)

Answer (score 4):

**YES**

1. Create a shortcut of the steam game;
2. Right-click the shortcut then go to 'Properties';
3. Copy the URL;
4. Go into the batch file and use **start (the url without brackets)**

For example my .bat file is:

```
@echo off
start steam://rungameid/730
cd D:\Desktop\csgo_dont_blind_me
start app.exe
exit
```

Comment: I don't think that's what they meant by this question. That lets you start the game from a batch environment, but I think they want to do the opposite: run a batch when (and ideally BEFORE) the game launches (from you choosing "play" in Steam). In my case, I'm trying to set it up so a batch can automatically synchronize my game files (i.e. over my home network) for a game that apparently doesn't support Steam Cloud Synchronization. Plus it would be nice to have an automatic backup subroutine in this case since I can't rely on steam to keep my data backed up.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer: No**

The Steam launch commands are no different from adding launch commands to the application's shortcut. It depends on each application what they will or won't parse. You can't run any scripts or anything, unless the game itself has such functionality, in which case, it's not relevant to steam launch commands.

There are different ways of executing commands on software launch, one of them being [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) scripts, which allows automatic command execution when a process is detected.
Another way would be creating a batch file that will execute the command and then run the game executable, although that may not work with all games (mmorpg's with cheat protection specifically). @Keavon's answer explains how to create an executable out of a batch file, so you can run it directly through steam, rather than through a shortcut.

Comment: This is a good thing for what its worth. It would be too easy to abuse a system that would let  you run scripts with out people being aware of them to start up key loggers or url re-directors and the like just because someone launched a steam game.

Comment: Nice idea, this seems less invasive than Keavon's solution, I'll try it. Thanks :)

Comment: @user3501165 Running an AutoHotKey script the entire time your computer is on to detect the launch of a game is a *lot* more invasive than simply running your script before it launches your game.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up by integrating it in an AutoHotkey script I was already using. I have to use a hotkey to run it, so it's not really automatic as I wanted it to be, but I prefer this instead of risking to trigger any anti-cheat Ban. Thanks :)

Comment: @user3501165 it is possible to set the script up to detect a process being launched and then execute the little bit of code, but it's complicated and probably not worth the hassle, if you don't mind using a hotkey.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit late, but you can issue any OS shell commands by using the keyword `%command%`. If that keyword is present in the options, it will run whatever you put in the options field on the command-line (`cmd.exe` on Windows, `/bin/sh` on mac OS and Linux) and substitute the keyword with the game's executable. You can separate different commands with semicolons, just like on the command-line.