# Trying to wrap game launch - Steam Linux

Tags: steam, linux

Similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225173/steam-launch-commands-a-way-to-launch-a-little-script?newreg=0d5f2f91df2242509eccaaf2ea5ddb9a), I'm trying to run a script to wrap the launch of a game simply for purposes of tracking how long I've been playing.

The way I have it set up currently is:

1. Move the original executable to a new filename, and make a bash script to replace it (making sure to mark it executable)
2. `curl` out a URL to notify a server (that's keeping timestamps, etc.) that I've started
3. Launch the actual game (using `$@` to make sure any options are sent in as well)
4. `curl` out a URL to notify a server that I'm done

I didn't think this would pose issues, but for whatever reason when actually running through Steam the `curl` command exits with status code [`48`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) and game begins as if nothing happened. If I just run the script by hand, `curl` runs successfully but the game notifies me that it can't connect to Steam.

Is there a way to actually wrap commands instead of just polling to determine if the game has launched? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After much research, it turns out that Steam adds its own libraries to the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, which is causing issues with the `curl` command finding the proper `libcurl`.

To fix this, record what your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable is when not running through Steam, and change it for the commands in the script with something like:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="" <my_command>
```